# Rewrite not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my htaccess I convert ? to # with the following:

```
# The below 2 lines will convert a ? to a # in the query.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/*(admin|access.php)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1#%{QUERY_STRING}? [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

What this does is convert ? to # unless the url has one of:

```
/admin
/access.php
```

So a url like the following won't get the ? converted:

```
http://mysite.com/access.php?login=special
```

However, now I have the requirement that a search parameter using the ? (not the #) be allowed to be used:

```
http://mysite.com/?s=somesearchstring&submit=Search
```

And I am floundering trying to get that to work. With the current rules the ? gets converted and I end up with:

```
http://mysite.com/#s=somesearchstring&submit=Search
```

But I need to NOT convert that ? to a #.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I honestly dont understand what you want... You first convert a ? to #, and than you say you dont want that. Remove the Rewrite rule and you're done... What is a typical caracteristic of strings you dont want to get converted? add that to the exception !^\/*(admin|access.php|someting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)s=.*?(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)submit=Search(&|$)
```

This won't modify `?` to `#` if ***both*** `s` and `submit` are present. They may appear in any order they like.

Comment: Thanks. My answer, below, worked but was lacking. Yours is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding the following works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=
```

But I worry that my lack of clear understanding of why might result in some problems.

Here is my understanding:

If the query string

```
!(does not)^(start with)s=
```

Am I missing anything? That does, at first glance, appear to solve my problem but perhaps it is incomplete or error prone?